# SlidingTabLayout left and right padding/margin

Tags: android, google-play, margin, padding

I'm trying to simulate the visual UI of the Google Play X in my app, and I'm having a hard time setting this margin/padding.

[image]

I tried o set padding to `SlidingTabLayout`, but it collapses automatically when any of the extremes (left or right) are selected.

I also tried modifying the source of the `SlidingTabLayout`, adding a margin to the `SlidingTabStrip`, without success.

My last attempt was to add margin to the first and last item of the `PagerAdapter`, in `SlidingTabLayout#populateTabStrip()`, again, without success.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did u find any solution to this problem? Because i also on the same boat.

Answer (score 4):

On populateTabStrip method of SlidingTabLayout add the following code before setting the tabTittleView text:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) tabTitleView.getLayoutParams();
final int padding = 20;
if(i == 0)
    mlp.setMargins((int) (padding * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density), 0, 0, 0);
else if (i == adapter.getCount()-1)
    mlp.setMargins(0, 0, (int) (padding * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density), 0);

tabTitleView.setLayoutParams(mlp);
```

Comment: Just to note, you'll also have to change `scrollToTab` - when it appends the title offset you'll have to change the condition from `if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0)` to `if (tabIndex > -1 || positionOffset > 0)`.